# Unboud variable using sass

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I used [https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDN6T.png) to boilerplate my angularjs application.

I discover bootswatch theme flatly and want to use it and downloaded from [http://bootswatch.com/flatly/][2] two files, _variables.scss and _bootswatch.scss.

I added these two files to my vendor.scss

```
$icon-font-path: "../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";

@import '../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';

@import "flatly/variables";
@import "flatly/bootswatch";
```

and with `gulp serve`, I build my application and on console it shows me.

```
project developer$ gulp serve
[21:28:41] Using gulpfile /Volumes/Developer/angularjs/project/gulpfile.js
[21:28:41] Starting 'styles'...
[21:28:42] gulp-inject 2 files into index.scss.

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: /Volumes/Developer/angularjs/project/src/app/flatly/_bootswatch.scss:16: error: unbound variable $navbar-default-bg 

  [1]: https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular
  [2]: http://bootswatch.com/flatly/
```

Why `unbound variable $navbar-default-bg` but the `$navbar-default-bg` exists in _variables.scss file.

> $navbar-default-bg:                $brand-primary;

My project structure:[image: structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the `_variables.scss` file at the beginning of your custom index.scss:

```
@import '../../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables';
```

Another way around could be following these instructions >> https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/issues/379. I haven't tried this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing in this order variables, bootstrap, bootswatch as per
https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/blob/gh-pages/global/build.scss

```
@import "flatly/variables";
@import '../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
@import "flatly/bootswatch";
```

The boilerplate attempts to compile all .scss files in the src folder (When it should ignore scss files starting with _).

Moving flaty outside of /src makes it behave eg

```
@import "../../flatly/variables";
@import '../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
@import "../../flatly/bootswatch";
```

Comment: This appears to be an issue with  https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular boilerplate.

It compiles _xxx.scss files when it is not suppose to

Comment: The boilerplate attempts to compile all .scss files in the src folder (When it should ignore scss files starting with _).

Comment: Updated my answer with a workaround... probably a better way of doing it, but I am unfamiliar with gulp. Probably worth logging an isue here https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/issues